# How to estimate gas for a solidity function params

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate

I have a function that takes multiple structs like so:

```
struct A {
 bytes myBytes1;
 bytes myBytes2;
 bytes myBytes3;
}

struct B {
 bytes myBytes1;
 bytes32 myBytes32;
 bytes myBytes3;
}

struct C {
 uint256 myInts1;
 bytes myBytes2;
 bytes myBytes3;
}

myFunction(A calldata a, B calldata b, C calldata c) external {
 // how to estimate gas for params: a,b,c?
 
 uint256 gasStart = gasleft();
 // code here
 uint256 gasDiff = gasStart - gasleft();

 // call an external contract to refund msg.sender
 // totalGasUsed: gasDiff + gas cost for params a,b,c
 // externalContract.refund(msg.sender, totalGasUsed)
}
```

The thing is that the data in structs params `a,b,c` can vary significantly and the difference in cost between sending less data vs a lot of data is significant. How do I calculate the total gas used by `myFunction`? Hardcoding additional gas is not an option, cause I don't know with what data this `myFunction` will be called. I can calculate the gas for the code inside of `myFunction`, but not sure how to calculate additional gas used by params: `a,b,c`.

Comment: The gas cost in the call data section are specified in [EIP 2028](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2028) 16 non-zero bytes and 4 zero bytes. Using encodeABI and estimateGas it should be fairly easy to compute off-chain, an on-chain computation probably will be to complicated.

Comment: It has to be done on-chain with the same refund transaction.